# Return non-zero exit code for crashed .NET Core BackgroundService

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-hosted-services, ihostedservice

Due to bugs in [`BackgroundService`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063) I'm using Stephen Cleary's excellent [workaround](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html). It works, but I can't return a non-zero exit code upon failure.

A minimal working example (for use with the `$ dotnet new worker` template):

`MyBackgroundService.cs`

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService {

  private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
  public MyBackgroundService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime) => _lifetime = lifetime;

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () => {
    try {
      while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (Random.Shared.NextDouble() < 0.5) throw new Exception("RANDOM CRASH!");
      }
    }
    catch {
      throw;         // I can hit a debug breakpoint here
    }
    finally {
      _lifetime.StopApplication();
    }
  });

}
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
public class Program {
  public static int Main(string[] args) {
    try {
      var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
      builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
      var host = builder.Build();
      host.Run();
      return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
      return 1;                // <----- execution never arrives here
    }
  }
}
```

When the app crashes, I expect the exit code to be `1`, but it is actually the default of `0`. When I debug it never enters the catch block.

What could be the reason?

Comment: The app didn't crash though, it terminated succesfully. Only the task that represents `ExecuteAsync` threw, and unless something awaits it, that exception won't be rethrown. The `IHostedService` interface doesn't even have an `ExecuteAsync`, only `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`. BackgroundService is a [convenience class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs) that handles graceful start and cancellation of the task returned by `ExecuteAsync`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting! If I understand correctly, that is the reason for Stephen Cleary's workaround of wrapping it in a Task.Run. Are you implying that the core problem is in the underlying implementation, and so there's nothing to be done (except wait for the fix in .net 8 or 9)?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. What are you trying to do? The specific scenario matters. Are you trying to log errors or integrate a long-running tool in a CLI script? Is there only one service or multiple? What happens if half the services fail, or they fail for different reasons? Why use a *service* at all? I've used a host builder and background services for ETL pipelines and I'd prefer to use System.CommandLine.Hosting if there's only one service

Comment: There's no problem in the implementation at all. When you have *10* background jobs in a web app, why would the entire site crash if one of the background jobs failed?

Comment: `When you have 10 background jobs in a web app, why would the entire site crash if one of the background jobs failed?` Erlang philosophy: crashing fast permits clean restarts. In my situation, I'd prefer to shutdown (and restart) the entire app if any service fails. That's vastly preferred over having a partially-working app. Note that I also always have clusters of at least 3 nodes, so app restarts don't cause system downtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my case: The (single) service reads messages from a queue and takes actions; if there's a problem the whole thing crashes (by design). Regarding System.CommandLine: one day, in the distant future, when it's released and is actually stable, it will be a phenomenal library. But I doubt that will ever happen; it's stuck in some kind of development hell situation. And the API breaks every few releases, so I can't build anything serious with it. Thanks for your advice above, it helped me understand the problem!

Comment: But you *are* using unstable code that's not suited for the task. I actually did the same back when there was no Generic host. System.CommandLine itself *is* stable, it's the hosting extensions that are a work in progress. BUT you only need the Generic host. Once we got a generic host, I removed the services. System.CommandLine.Hosting just makes integration between the CLI parser and the generic host easier

Comment: `reads messages from a queue` [Wolverine](https://wolverine.netlify.app/guide/command-line.html) comes with its own CLI integration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. I haven't used it in a while... I'll revisit it and reconsider.

Comment: `System.CommandLine.Hosting just makes integration between the CLI parser and the generic host easier` That's good to know; I haven't used S.CL.H yet. I do regularly use both S.CL and the worker process template (for separate projects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually because the task returned from `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync` is [ignored](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html) (as explained on my blog). So, even though you're shutting down the host, the exception is still ignored.

Hosted services don't have a way to report exceptions or exit codes. Your options are:

- Define your own `BackgroundService`-derived type that exposes its `Task` and have your main loop resolve instances of your derived type and await those tasks. This will observe exceptions from the background services.
- Have your background services set `Environment.ExitCode` if they fail, similar to [this code on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/servicebase-gotcha-recovery-actions.html). Then your `Main` can return `void`.

Both of these approaches do an "end run" around the app lifetime because the .NET host wasn't designed to allow background service results. I use the second one myself since the same code works for both worker processes and SCM services.

Comment: There are better options than this. If there's only one service - why use a service? System.Commandline and hosting would do the work. As for reporting the status of *10* background services, the best option would be an explicit reporting interface/service/middleware. Most of the time we *don't* want a single background job out of 10 to crash the entire application

Comment: Thanks! I saw that example for windows/scm but I'm on linux so I couldn't use it. Though I used that idea to create a (hacky) solution, posted below.

Comment: I saw your comment on that github issue. It's a pity they won't fix those issues for the v8 release. :(

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `System.Commandline` is (and has been) a moving target and not particularly well documented.  It may be the right answer one day, but as of March 2024, I wouldn't advise it.  For more info, see [the announcement from earlier this month](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/2338) indicating a "reset" of the project

Comment: @BenCollins that wasn't yet the case in 2023 - or at least it only seemed to be "slightly delayed" as far as the NuGet packages were concerned. The current code and samples though have little in common with the NuGet packages

Comment: Never mind that few people would call a GH issue an actual announcement - that's what DevBlogs is (was) supposed to be. The announcement itself essentially means System.CommandLine failed. And Aaron Stannard can have a good laugh with people that assumed an MS package would be more stable

Answer (score 0):

The workarounds in the accepted answer are good. But I chose the lazy route:

`MyBackgroundService.cs`

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService {

  private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
  public MyBackgroundService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime) => _lifetime = lifetime;

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () => {
    var exitCode = 0;                                  // <---------
    try {
      while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (Random.Shared.NextDouble() < 0.5) throw new Exception("RANDOM CRASH!");
      }
    }
    catch {
      exitCode = 1;                                    // <---------
      throw;
    }
    finally {
      if (Environment.ExitCode == 0 && exitCode != 0)  // <---------
        Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;               // <---------
      _lifetime.StopApplication();
    }
  });

}
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
// ...
host.Run();
return Environment.ExitCode;                           // <---------
```

Comment: If there's only one service, why use BackgroundService at all? You put the `ExecuteAsync` code in another DI service and call that instead of `host.Run`, returing whatever result you need

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I kept it simple for the purpose of the question. There is one "primary" background service, with many DI dependencies. But there's also a few non-primary background services too, which read different messages from the queue. So I chose to use the generic host. I might move them to separate apps, so will reconsider based on this experience and your recommendations above.